# how to access global variables / or used port in front end, while running server by nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, frontend, backend

I have

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
  //__dirname : It will resolve to your project folder.
});
```

calling index.html file. It has script tag with script.

Calling of environmental variable in app.js file works well

```
var port =process.env.port ||process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

but error starts if I run this in the script tag of index.html

How can I access PORT environmental variable in that script tag? Is there way to run separate index.js file
(I used `<script src="./index.js"/>` and

```
alert()
console.log("s")
```

in that file, but it did nothing)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access environment variables directly on the client-side (`index.html`), but you can inject them in response or expose them as API endpoint and call it later from client-side.

1. Write `port` to response and return as `text/html`.

   ```
   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     return res.send(`Application listening at ${process.env.PORT || port}.`);
   });
   ```
2. Return `port` as `application/json`

   ```
   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     return res.send({ port: process.env.PORT || port })
   });
   ```

Comment: without knowing port I could not ask from front end , got to this trap

But advice about <script>
 var port = window.location.port;
 alert(port);
</script> is good

Comment: I already send whole html file to app.get('/',
so I cannot send there port or anything else

Answer (score 0):

This in your html will give you the port used.

```
window.location.port
```

eg:

```
<script>
 var port = window.location.port;
 alert(port);
</script>
```